# Is there any event to detect win.reload completion

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm using electron JS to build an app. I want to reload my app after reconnect. Need to show a loader window while reloading and hide after complete. Is there any way to do it?

I don't want to put loader inside my app. I like to show it in a separate [browser window](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window).

I'm expecting like this

```js
BrowserWindow.on('reload-complete', (e) => {
  hideLoadingWindow();
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I got another method to overcome this situation. I'm not sure is it a good solution. but it looks simple to me.

```js
    var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: false,
        preload: path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'preload.js')
      },
      minWidth: 1018,
      width: 640,
      minHeight: 1018,
      height: 640,
      title: 'Electron app',
      show: false
    });

    createLoadingWindow();

    mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {      
      mainWindow.show();
    });

    mainWindow.webContents.on('did-start-loading', (e) => {
      createLoadingWindow();
    });

    mainWindow.webContents.on('did-stop-loading', (e) => {
      closeLoadingWindow();
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

The event below is the correct one for you:

```
BrowserWindow.webContents.once('did-finish-load', (e) => {
  //hideLoadingWindow();
})
```

the `'did-finish-load'` event will be triggered after the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use show method and then use 'dom-ready' to detect your app loading ,

```
  let loading= new BrowserWindow({show: false, frame: false})

  loading.once('show', () => {
    main = new BrowserWindow({show: false})
    main.webContents.once('dom-ready', () => {
      console.log('main loaded')
      main.show()
      loading.hide()
      loading.close()
    })
    // load your app
    main.loadURL(url);
  })
```